# Convert dynamically the page title from mysql or php script

Tags: php

Please help me in changing the page title automatically when a new article is posted.
currently it looks like http://www.fxstoc.com/detailed_news.php?newsid=24
but i wish to have title header instead of newsid=24

Comment: Just make sure it's in the `<title></title>` attribute in your page header

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify value in

```
<title></title>
```

For example:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Comment: is it enough just to add in the title tag?

Comment: In `$title` you have specify your title depending on the current page.

Comment: I like pull this as automated from my mysql database where news table having heading as title of the post